# Horizontally image movement based on the vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

Plase check this website:

http://www.agencynet.com/

I don't understand how to control the movement of green dots.

How I can do to make the green dot react to scroll?

```
$(function(){

     $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
         && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

             var $target = $(this.hash);

             $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

             if ($target.length) {

                 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

                 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                 $('#punto').animate({'marginLeft': targetOffset/2}, 1000);
                 return false;

            }

       }

   });

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
// animate your green dot according to the scrolltop value here
// e.g. $('.dot').stop().animate({left:(scrolltop/1000.0)*100+'px'});
});
```

one word of advice: animating on every scroll update can result in slugish performance with smooth scrolling browsers. in this case it is better, to start your animation only after scrolling stopped or at least with some minimal timeout

Comment: Thanks! the dot is moving!

I do not know how to match the green dot above gray dot. In the web have seen that each project occupies the same height, therefore, the movement is always the same distance.
Any ideas?
Thank you very much, is helping me a lot.